# C# encryption in DES

Tags: c#, encryption, des

I have a key which is in hex as `1C19D5ED8D88DC40` and the data in hex as `041164DFFFFE7FF7`.

I am supposed to do **DES encryption** to obtain the encrypted value in hex as `B652FF1BA23C279B`.  i struggled a lot with all possible encrypting methods of DES but couldn't get the exact value. I found it in this [link](http://mavroudisv.eu/des/index.php) I passed the binary values of the above hex as input and got the desired.

Help with C# code to get the above value.

```
    public static string Encrypt(string Data,string Key)
{
    byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
    // byte[] iv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password");
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
    byte[] enc = new byte[0];
    TripleDES tdes = TripleDES.Create();
    //tdes.IV = iv;
    tdes.Key = key;
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    ICryptoTransform ict = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
    enc = ict.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
    return Bin2Hex(enc);

}
// my bin2hex implementation        
static string Bin2Hex(byte[] bin)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bin.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in bin)
    {
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x").PadLeft(2, '0'));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: please post your work so that we could start our work...

Comment: Please show us what you struggled a lot with...

Comment: have added the code I used.

Comment: I would recommend finding a set of Known-Answer vectors for 3des using options other than the one you are currently testing to try to see if you can get *anything* to work with your code.  Last time I worked on crypto, I found that technique super-helpful and it ironed out all my bugs.  You could also try looking here for some help:  http://crypto.stackexchange.com/